# How to get the last number in a string and +1?

Tags: python

I need to find the last number occurrence (not a single digit) in a string, and replace with `number+1`, for example: `/path/testcase9.in` to `/path/testcase10.in`. How to do this in python more nicely or efficiently?

Here is what I am using now:

```
reNumber = re.compile('(\d+)')

def getNext(path):
    try:
        number = reNumber.findall(path)[-1]
    except:
        return None
    pos = path.rfind(number)
    return path[:pos] + path[pos:].replace(number, str(int(number)+1))

path = '/path/testcase9.in'
print(path + " => " + repr(self.getNext(path)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LAST_NUMBER = re.compile(r'(\d+)(?!.*\d)')

def getNext(path):
    return LAST_NUMBER.sub(lambda match: str(int(match.group(1))+1), path)
```

This uses [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) and in particular, the ability to have the "replacement" be a function that's called with the original match to determine what should replace it.

It also uses a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion to make sure the regex only matches the last number in the string.

Answer (score 0):

by using ".*" in your re, you can select all characters before the last digit (since it's greedy):

```
import re

numRE = re.compile('(.*)(\d+)(.*)')

test = 'somefile9.in'
test2 = 'some9file10.in'

m = numRE.match(test)
if m:
    newFile = "%s%d%s"%(m.group(1),int(m.group(2))+1,m.group(3))
    print(newFile)

m = numRE.match(test2)
if m:
    newFile = "%s%d%s"%(m.group(1),int(m.group(2))+1,m.group(3))
    print(newFile)
```

The result is:

```
somefile10.in
some9file11.in
```